# Квадратные скобки слева от вызова функции?

Tags: php

Нашел в коде

```
[$pointer, $prefixLen] = $this->findAddressInTree($ipAddress);

[$record] = $this->getWithPrefixLen($ipAddress);
```

Кто может пояснить за смысл этих скобок?

На вторую строку ругается Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '='

Это пхп 8?

Comment: маловероятно, что на первую не ругается, а на вторую ругается.

Answer (score 2):

Это *PHP7.1* и это краткая запись функции **[list](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.list.php)**

Comment: будем точны в терминологии, `list` это не функция а языковая конструкция )

Comment: @teran "Руководство по PHP - Справочник функций - Расширения, относящиеся к переменным и типам - Массивы - Функции для работы с массивами" --- ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯  я слушаюсь и повинуюсь :D

Comment: во первых, функция не может стоять слева от `=`, во вторых по самой приведенной ссылке первым в тексте написано _"Подобно array(), это не функция, а языковая конструкция"_  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @teran я шучу))